# How to scroll a layout on top of another only when user scrolls

Tags: android

I want to scroll a layout on top of another layout. Example there is an Image inn the top, below image (bottom 10% overllaped) I have a relative layout which contains data. When user starts scrolling up, this relative layout has to over the top image and attach to toolbar, top image should be in the same state (no change in height). When user scrolls down it should come back to original place. I searched a lot but ended up with nothing.

For example :

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/testIv"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"/>
    
    <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/testIv"
        android:background="@color/red">
        
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Hello World"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="30sp"/>
    </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

In this example I have an Imageview and below that a scrollview, when user try to scroll, the scroll should over the imageview and reach the top toolbar.

Updated :

```
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

<com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appBar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="300dp"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsingToolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
        app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/toolbarImage"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"/>

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
</com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

<androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="28sp"
        android:lineSpacingExtra="8dp"
        android:text="@string/large_text" />
</androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

In this example, when we scroll, it will collapse the image also, tried with different avlues for scrollFlags and collapseMode.

Expected UI :

[image]

Comment: Right now your question does not make much sense. Seems like need of `CoordinatorLayout` . Pls add a [mcve] to make the question clear enough to answer . You can add a GIF to show the expected result .

Comment: @ADM I have added a sample XML code. Please check. Just to make you understand the UI, I have taken relative layout.

Comment: Looks you need [CoordinatorLayout with CollapsingToolbar](https://www.androidauthority.com/using-coordinatorlayout-android-apps-703720) , check point#3 of this article.

Comment: @user8608556 I have tried this way, this will collapse the top image also. In my requirement image should not collapse.

Comment: @user8608556 I have updated my question. Please check.

Comment: @madhuriHR this achieves want you wanted. collapsing image or hiding over below layout really doesn't make much difference as ultimately you are making below layout visible. Moreover this collapsing gives better UX.

Comment: @user8608556 Its the requirement from the client that image should not collapse, it should stay same when user scrolls (In the below layout left and right margins are there, this makes the image visible). Can we achive this by giving any other value to scrollFlags ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Achieving this with BottomSheet behavior on ScrollView keeping image `collapseMode` inside CoordinateLayout to `none`. [I have created sample demo check it here](https://github.com/prasad-333/BottomSheetDemo) and added comments for your better understanding.

[Demo screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rv3Xr.png)

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted. Thank you for your answer. Instead of keeping the NSV at the bottom, how can I place it below image (height around 200dp), NSV in the top has to 20% overlap the imageview. This I am able to achive once we scroll, but when we open the screen it is coming below imageview.

Comment: I have added [comments here](https://github.com/prasad-333/BottomSheetDemo/blob/master/app/src/main/res/layout/activity_main.xml) for your understanding. Did you tried those? You can adjust `app:behavior_peekHeight` to show how much of NSV will be visible.

Comment: Yes I gave peekHeight, but when I open it is taking some height and once I scroll height is changing. I tried giving it programatically also. I tried with negative marginTop. This is working only after user scrolls.

Comment: @madhuriHR didn't get you. can you share video/screenshots for what you want to change further?

Comment: I have attached the Image for expected UI. For this to achive i gave margin top -20dp. When the screen is opened, this margin is not considered, once the user scrolls up and then down, this margin is getting applied.

Comment: If I use peekHeight, when screen is launched  (for example i gave 1000 programativally) it is taking half of the screen, if user scrolls the list up and down, it is taking more than half the screen.

Comment: @madhuriHR If you see my demo screenshot uploaded while answer, it is as you expected. Do you want NSV to be displayed below image fully in screen on launch? if yes, then its not what NSV is used for & its completely depends on your data length & screen-size. Just fork the branch & run the app as it is.

Comment: Yes I have seen your app, in that NSV is coming in the bottom. What i want is image is displayed in 25% of screen height. Then NSV, which overlaps by around 20dp.

Comment: Ok, then in that case you need to set the height for imageView as per that you need to set the behavior_peekHeight. To make sure it work on all different screen size, you need to do this dynamically, calculate screen height & set 25% of it to imageView height. Remaining height will be peekHeight + 20dp(your desired overlap).

Comment: I have done in the same way. It is working fine but when notifydatasetchanged() is called to adapter in recyclerview, it is behaving differently, it is getting scrolled down and taking top blank space.

Comment: Check on different ways to notify data changed for recyclerview instead redrawing it entirely, notify only required changes or check on diffUtil for any other option.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223634/discussion-between-madhuri-h-r-and-333).